# What is sibling of son-in-law or daughter-in-law called?

Tags: kinship-terminology, terminology

Is there a term for the sibling of ones son-in-law or daughter-in-law? 
Real-life example: The composer Dohnanyi had a son who married a sister of Dietrich Bonhoeffer. So Dohnanyi was the father of Bonhoeffer's brother-in-law, or the father-in-law of Bonhoeffer's sister.

Is there an accepted term for this relationship?

Answer (score 5):

With respect to Dohnanyi, Dietrich Bonhoeffer could be referred to as:

1. His son's wife's brother (for most detail),
2. His son's brother-in-law, or
3. His daughter-in-law's brother.

Relatives through marriage are generally known as "affines" or "in-laws", and only the close relationships have a specific term.

This is only for English. There may be one or more other languages that have a term for this relationship.

Answer (score 4):

[Steve Morse's relationship calculator](http://stevemorse.org/relation/calculator.html) shows that there is no blood relationship and no English term.